# Stop Auto Invoice Generation for Braintree payment method

Tags: magento, magento2, payment-gateway, braintree

I want to stop invoice creation for braintree online payment methods.
I know if we configure only Authorize and not the Authorize and capture then it can be achieved but I have set Authorize & capture and I want to stop invoice from creating.

After debugging I have found capture method of class

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Payment/Operations/CaptureOperation.php
```

which is generating the invoice.

Comment: An invoice is normally a bill that is sent to a customer, to be paid later, but that doesn't sound like what you mean? What is the thing you want Braintree to stop generating?

Comment: @mattfreake basically we are going to integrate ERP for all order level functions like invoice, ship and credit memos. So we want whenever customer places order using any online payment method, Braintree or PayPal invoice should not be generated for that order. Firstly ERP team will review that order then they will generate invoice for that order by api

Comment: If the invoice isn't generated until later, I don't understand what the customer is doing with the online payment method earlier. Surely they don't need to use an online payment method until they receive the invoice?

Comment: (it might just be I don't know the typical ERP flow...)